# Post AJAX API Javascript SAPUI5 failed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, sapui5

I want to use POST method with AJAX in SAPUI5 javascript but I found an error.

```js
var url = "https://xxxx*xxxx.co.id:8877/TaspenSAP/SimpanDosirPunah";

$.ajax({ 
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: JSON.stringify({
        nomorDosir: "01001961288",
        kodeCabang: "A02"
    }),
    dataType: "json",
    async: false,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function(data, textStatus, xhr){        
        console.log("sukses: " + data + " " + JSON.stringify(xhr));
    },
    error: function (e,xhr,textStatus,err,data) {
        console.log(e);
        console.log(xhr);
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

error:

[image]

I already did change code with `dataType=text`, or data: `{nomorDosir: "01001961288", kodeCabang: "A02"}` (without stringify), but I not yet find the solution. How to fix this problem?

Thanks. 
Bobby

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what your use case is but if you are trying to post to an `oData` service, it might be much easier to use SAPs `createEntry` method where the URL is the path to the model you want to post to and your JSON are the properties:

```js
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel("https://services.odata.org/V2/OData/OData.svc/");
//oModel should use your service uri
var url = "https://xxxx*xxxx.co.id:8877/TaspenSAP/SimpanDosirPunah";
oModel.createEntry(url, {
  properties: {
    nomorDosir: "01001961288",
    kodeCabang: "A02"
  }

}, {
  method: "POST",
  success: function(response) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(response));
    //do something
  },
  error: function(error) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(error));
  }
});
oModel.submitChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have is wrong `json` format, you have:

```
data: JSON.stringify({nomorDosir: "01001961288", kodeCabang: "A02"}),
```

Which actually should be:

```
data: {"nomorDosir": "01001961288", "kodeCabang": "A02"},
```

Which then you don't need to do a `json.stringify` on, because it already IS a json format. Hope this will help you out.

---

Which you could also try is setting a variable outside like this:

```
var url = "https://xxxx*xxxx.co.id:8877/TaspenSAP/SimpanDosirPunah";
var json = {"nomorDosir": "01001961288", "kodeCabang": "A02"};

$.ajax({ 
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: json,
    dataType: "json",
    async: false,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function(data, textStatus, xhr){        
        console.log("sukses: "+data+" "+JSON.stringify(xhr));
    },
    error: function (e,xhr,textStatus,err,data) {
        console.log(e);
        console.log(xhr);
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

Comment: still error. SyntaxError: Unexpected token r in JSON at position 1 at JSON.parse

Comment: how to fix this problem?

Comment: @bobby why is there a `JSON.parse`? Where are you declaring this?

Comment: No.. I dont know, I just want consume api service post..  For your opinion, where is wrong? In java (backend system) or javascript (frontend)?

Comment: Wait. You have done a `succes` function which is outdated `ajax`, ajax works with `.done`. Also, where are you doing a `json.parse`?

Comment: I dont using json.parse. I just consume API POST with java where what has been made.

Comment: Try to look at how to do a `.done` instead of a `succes`

Comment: You can `console.log` when you use a `.done` function. Because I did that myself.